# What happens when you fail to pay your Google One subscription?

Tags: google-one

I do all of the following from my Android phone. I use access to 100GB of storage with my Google One subscription, of which I have used, roughly, 75GB. The default amount of Google storage is 15GB. By paying, a minimal amount, I have my cloud storage quota increased to 100GB. However, it may happen that when the automatic payment is processed, the funds are not available on my card.

Someone suggested that in this case some of your files may not be available, and they may appear deleted.

Is this the case? What happens to your files, and how does file access/inaccessibility present itself when payment fails?

Answer (score 2):

There was an interesting question asked on [WebApps StackExchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54347/what-happens-when-you-no-longer-pay-for-your-google-storage) about this.

I'll just quote the important part:

> if you exceed your storage quota for 2 years, your content across Gmail, Drive, and
> Photos may be deleted. Gmail You can’t send or receive messages.
> Messages sent to you are returned to the sender. Google Drive You
> can’t sync or upload new files. You can’t create new files in Google
> Docs, Sheets, Slides, Drawings, Forms, and Jamboard. Until you reduce
> the amount of storage you use, neither you nor anyone else can edit or
> copy your affected files. Syncs stop between your computer's Google
> Drive folder and My Drive. Google Photos
>
> You can’t back up any photos or videos. If you want to add any more
> photos and videos,

Current google support [Link](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374270?hl=en&ref_topic=2375005&visit_id=638404195378510998-192673590&rd=1#zippy=%2Cgoogle-drive%2Cgoogle-photos%2Cgmail) of the same